# Angular get the current routes

Tags: angular, routes, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create the custom breadcrumb. I would like to get the current routes without dataid.

I have tried the below but it is coming with data ID and routing is not working.

Expert advice please.

Actual link: http://localhost:4200/settings/data?dataId=1100

**HTML**

```
<ul >
  <li class="breadcrumb-item" *ngFor="let breadLink of breadcrumbListObj"><a [routerLink]="breadLink.link">{{breadLink.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**TS**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Location } from '@angular/common';
    import {Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, RoutesRecognized, Params, PRIMARY_OUTLET} from '@angular/router'
    constructor(location: Location, activate: ActivatedRoute, router:Router) {

      router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (location.path() !== '') {
        this.route = location.path();
        this.breadcrumbListArray = this.route.split('/');
        for(let d of this.breadcrumbListArray) {
         this.breadcrumbListObj["link"] = "/" + d;
         this.breadcrumbListObj["name"] = d;
        }
      }

  });
```

**Expected breadcrumb path is => settings/data with respective routes on click on settings**

Comment: In the constructor inject `private router: Router` and then you can use `this.router.url` to access the current route

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a few ways to get the current route without the parameters ('?dataId=1100').

These are the 2 ways you can do it with Vanilla JavaScript.

```
console.log(`${location.protocol}//${location.host}${location.pathname}`);
console.log(window.location.href.split('?')[0]);
```

Otherwise, you can use Angular's `Router` module from the `@angular/router` package.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
  console.log(this.router.url.split('?')[0]);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for only routes like settings/data.  This one 'console.log(window.location.href.split('?')[0]);' gives complete url.

Comment: Not needed to use Vanilla. Angular Route instanced at this.router already have all route information.

Comment: How to separate this "settings/data?dataId=1100" to "settings/data"

Comment: @VitorPiovezam Thanks vitor. You are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
this.activate.queryParams.filter(params => params.dataId).subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params);
     this.dataId = params.dataId;
     console.log(this.dataId); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You would need the ActivatedRoute Object from the router and use it to get the url and strip the part you want sans the params as below.

```
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
 console.log(this.route.routeConfig.path.split('?')[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `ActivatedRoute` that contains information about the url segments. One gotcha is that it points to the route on which the component is rendered, not the most recent route. I'm guessing your breadcrumb will be rendered in some root component so that it displays anywhere on the page. What you can do is get the children of the route and find the most recent route this way. Something like `while(route.firstChild) route=route.firstChild`. You will need to trigger the refresh of your breadcrumb, too. To do that you can for example subscribe to the router events.